# Django .save() doesn't take effect

Tags: django

I would like to understand why I need to rerun the Django server in order to watch the effect of `.save()` method.

When I upload a new document, I use code that lets me see if the document is recent or not. For example, I set the expiration time to 15 seconds after the upload part (15 seconds is for testing purposes, it will be 1 week in production).

I have this class :

```
class DocumentListView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'documentList.html'
    form_class = DocumentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()

        for document in Document.objects.all():
            expiration_delay = document.creation_date + timedelta(seconds=15)
            if now > expiration_delay:
                document.new_document = False
                document.save()

        kwargs['document_list'] = Document.objects.all().order_by('publication__category__name')

        return super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

It works fine, but after 15 seconds, when I want to refresh my page, the flag is still there. It disappears only when I rerun my Django server.

Comment: Both code snippets show that `timezone.now()` is called when `get_context_data` runs, so you should see the same behaviour from both of them. If `now = timezone.now()` was outside of `get_context` data (e.g. at the class or module level), then it would be called once when the server starts, and not updated until you reload your server.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok so `now = timezone.now()` should be outside of `get_context_data` if I want to refresh my page and see if document is recent or not (with flag) ?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood my comment. The common mistake is to put `timezone.now()` outside of the method, so it is only called once when the server is started/restarted. In both your examples, `timezone.now()` is called every time `get_context_data()` is called, therefore you should see the same behaviour from both examples.

Comment: As an aside, note that `return document` will give an error when there are no documents in the database.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. I will make some modifications and I have to add `Exception` if I have no documents in my database ?

Comment: You don't use the result of `flag_document`, so I would just remove the `return document` line to prevent it causing an error.